# ncftp: login, move to directory directly from console and keep interactive shell open

Tags: shell, ftp, directory

It is maybe trivial, but ..
I want to connect with ncftp to a server and move to a directory and tehn have the interactive shell open. I want a shell command that directly brings me to the folder, no cd after login.

```
ncftp -u user -p  passwd  host <<< "cd move/do/dir"
```

does not work. Session is terminated immediately.

```
ncftp -u user -p  passwd  ftp://host/move/do/dir
```

does not work.>> Use ncftpget or ncftpput to handle file URLs.